# Constructor does not initialize class element

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, size-t

I'm working on a class that generates a string made of random characters, of a given size. I'm passing the `m_size` value to the constructor, as you can see in the following code:

```
class Random_Generator
{
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    std::mt19937 m_dev;
    clock::time_point m_beginning;
    std::string m_value;
    size_t m_size;

    long long TimeSeed();
    std::string Generated();

public:
    Random_Generator(size_t sz)
        : m_dev(TimeSeed())
        , m_beginning(clock::now())
        , m_size(sz)
        , m_value(Generated())
    {}
    // other methods
};

int main()
{
    Random_Generator rstr(10);
    // more code
}
```

The thing is, `m_size` does not initialize with the value of `sz`: when debugging (I'm using Visual Studio community 2019, if that's useful), it seems that when the constructor executes, it simply jumps over the initialization of `m_size`, thus `m_size` having a garbage value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you debugging a release build?  If you are the code will not behave like you wrote it and this type of behavior is normal.

Comment: The constructor initializes the elements in the order they were declared. Step through it a bit more and you'll see that `m_size` eventually gets initialized.

Comment: Please show us, in the form of [mre], that it isn't initialized.

Comment: @0x499602D2 declaring m_size before m_value fixed the "problem", I thought that elements are initialized in the order they are written in the constructor.

Comment: @pixusnixus some compilers have a warning for cases like this ([for example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b4669d05cf2d411))

Comment: @pixusnixus "_I thought that elements are initialized in the order they are written in the constructor._" Why did you think so? What source told you this?

Comment: I guess I overlooked that, because I didn't learn that from a specific place. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Class members are initialized in the order that they are declared in the class, regardless of the order of values specified in the constructor's initialization list.  As such, in the code shown, `m_value` is initialized before `m_size`.  Does your `Generated()` method depend on `m_size` being set first?

Comment: Yes, it depends, that was the problem!